# MSSQL PHP Question

Tags: apache-2.2, sql-server, php, centos

If I am running a Centos Server with Apache and PHP, what do I need to do to enable connections to a MSSQL server? I have heard that this functionality is not included by default in PHP. So how do I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can start here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php